# SQL Server 2005. Full Text Search. Need Thesaurus working with NEAR/AND/OR keywords

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-search, thesaurus

does anyone know if it's possible to do a thesaurus search
together with NEAR or AND/OR keywords.
Here is an example of the type of query I want to run:

```
    SELECT Title, RANK
            FROM Item INNER JOIN
            CONTAINSTABLE(Item, Title, 'FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "red" NEAR "wine")') AS KEY_TBL
            ON Item.ItemID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
    ORDER BY RANK DESC
```

....But I get the error message:

Syntax error near 'NEAR' in the full-text search condition 'FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "red" NEAR "wine")'.

Answer (score 1):

Near and FormsOf don't work well with each other. Read the following link
[Is it possible to combine NEAR and FORMSOF together in a fulltext search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682825/is-it-possible-to-combine-near-and-formsof-together-in-a-fulltext-search)

use `IsAbout`

```
SELECT   K.RANK, name, Description
FROM      Diagnosis AS C
INNER JOIN
CONTAINSTABLE(diagnosis,name, 'ISABOUT (
FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "red"),
FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "wine"))', 50) AS K
ON C.ID = K.[KEY];
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of thesaurus is slightly different, you you might be looking for is something like:

```
SELECT Title, RANK
            FROM Item INNER JOIN
            CONTAINSTABLE(Item, Title, 'FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "red") NEAR FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "wine")') AS KEY_TBL
            ON Item.ItemID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
    ORDER BY RANK DESC
```