# Is it possible to combine NEAR and FORMSOF together in a fulltext search?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have this:

`SELECT * FROM AwesomePeople WHERE CONTAINS(Name, 'NEAR(("Nathan", "Fillion"), MAX, TRUE)')`

But I want to combine it so it uses my thesaurus of words to look at alternatives for `Nathan` and `Fillion`.

I can do this:

`SELECT * FROM AwesomePeople WHERE CONTAINS(Name, 'FORMSOF (THESAURUS, "Nathan"))`

But I don't know how to search for 2 words, or make it do FORMSOF and NEAR together in a single query. I have tried a few combinations but am out of luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using SQL Server 2012 as 'NEAR(("Nathan", "Fillion") is the newer form of proximity search, called custom proximity search.

From technet:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142568%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

> You cannot combine a custom proximity term with a generic proximity
>   term (term1 NEAR term2), a generation term (ISABOUT …), or a weighted
>   term (FORMSOF …).

and also lower down

> You cannot combine a generic proximity term with a custom proximity
>   term, such as NEAR((term1,term2),5), a weighted term (ISABOUT …), or a
>   generational term (FORMSOF …).

Technet seems to have the ISABOUT and FORMSOF mixed up in the first quote, but either way ISABOUT or FORMSOF terms cannot be combined with a NEAR term.

Answer (score 2):

Following will work great. It is more powerful.

```
SELECT  * FROM AwesomePeople AS C INNER JOIN
CONTAINSTABLE(AwesomePeople ,name, 'ISABOUT (
    FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "Nathan"),
    FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "Fillion"))') AS K
ON C.ID = K.[KEY];
```